# Post titles not letting me use 2 consecutive dashes in permalink

Tags: permalinks

I have a site where YouTube video IDs are used as a post's title. This mostly works fine, except some valid YouTube video IDs have two consecutive dashes. For example, "j--c0wP54JU" is getting automatically modified by wordpress to be "j-c0wP54JU" (Note the single dash).

When I try to manually edit the permalink from the Edit Post page, it keeps removing the 2 consecutive dashes when I press OK.

Where can I disable this part of Wordpress that changes the URLs to be "web safe"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding the **why** part, I think I've traced this to the following [line](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/formatting.php#L1378):

```
$title = preg_replace('|-+|', '-', $title);
```

within the [`sanitize_title_with_dashes()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/formatting.php#L1378) function.

It's added to the `santize_title()` via the filter:

```
add_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'sanitize_title_with_dashes', 10, 3 );
```

but I wouldn't recommend removing it totally.

### Update:

Here's a quick and dirty way around this:

```
add_filter( 'sanitize_title', function( $title )
{
    return str_replace( '--', 'twotempdashes', $title );
},9 );


add_filter( 'sanitize_title', function( $title )
{
    return str_replace( 'twotempdashes', '--', $title );
},11 );
```

where we replace two dashes into some temporary string, before the `sanitize_title_with_dashes` is activated and then replace the string again to two dashes afterwards. We could adjust this to the more general case, but you get the idea ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The culprit here is [`sanitize_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title/) via the [`sanitize_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/sanitize_title/) hook. The function hooked to it is [`sanitize_title_with_dashes()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title_with_dashes/); I see @birgire tracked it down too, as it can be seen in [`wp-includes/default-filters.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L186).

> add_filter( 'sanitize_title',           'sanitize_title_with_dashes',   10, 3 );

You can use [`remove_filter()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_filter/) to do just that.

```
remove_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'sanitize_title_with_dashes', 10 );
```

But **beware**, you are not longer sanitizing your titles now, which really is **not** recommended. @birgire is absolutely right about the why part, but you can't change that easily so I would recommend duplicating `sanitize_title_with_dashes()`, leaving out the "bad" part. Use `add_filter()` to hook your custom filter function to `sanitize_title`.